# Building Packages success in My Machine but fails on Launchpad PPA

Tags: package-management, ppa, packaging, launchpad

I'm trying to build budgie-desktop debian packages and upload it to my launchpad ppa.
Building Packages success in My Machine but fails on Launchpad PPA(with the following errors)

```
make[2]: Entering directory `/build/buildd/budgie-desktop-2.0/session'
Makefile:516: ../data/.deps/budgie_session_dialog-budgie-session-dialog-resources.Po: No such file or directory
make[2]: *** No rule to make target `../data/.deps/budgie_session_dialog-budgie-session-dialog-resources.Po'.  Stop.
make[2]: Leaving directory `/build/buildd/budgie-desktop-2.0/session'
make[1]: *** [distclean-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/build/buildd/budgie-desktop-2.0'
dh_auto_clean: make -j1 distclean returned exit code 2
make: *** [clean] Error 2
dpkg-buildpackage: error: /usr/bin/fakeroot debian/rules clean gave error exit status 2
```

You can check out the full log in the following build status

[Build Status]

amd64 build : 
https://launchpad.net/~sukso96100/+archive/budgie-desktop/+build/5924020

i386 build :
https://launchpad.net/~sukso96100/+archive/budgie-desktop/+build/5924021

What should i do to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, the `clean` target is run first, and then the `build` and `install` (or `binary`, I'm not sure which) are run. In your clean target, you are calling `rm -rf ../data/.deps ./.deps applets/.deps common/.deps`, which removes the `../data/.deps` folder, and so it can't find `../data/.deps/budgie_session_dialog-budgie-session-dialog-resources.Po`.

Running `debuild` before uploading to a PPA can help find these types of errors.